# How to loop thru child list<Object>?

Tags: swift, realm

i try to loop thru list in child object in Realm database. `List<Word>` in every `topic` has two elements, but `topic.words` is empty ( How can I access to the child list for every `topic` in `topics` ?

```
let topics = Realm().objects(Topic)
for topic in topics {
        println(topic.description)
        //prints Topic {
        //    name_en = Family;
        //    words = RLMArray <0x7ff6b4b2a380> (
        //    [0] Word {
        //    name_en = Mother;
        //    },
        //    [1] Word {
        //    name_en = Father;
        //    }
        //    );
        //}

        println(topic.words)
        //prints
        //  List<Word> (
        //
        //    )

        for word in topic.words {
            println(word.name_en)
        }
```

what am I doing wrong with List ?
Why List is empty ?

My model is:

```
class Word: Object {
    dynamic var name_en = ""
    var owners: [Topic] {
        return linkingObjects(Topic.self, forProperty: "words")
    }
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "name_en"
    }
}
class Topic: Object {
    dynamic var name_en = ""
    let words = List<Word>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name_en"
    }
}
```

for example this code for one `topic` works properly:

```
    var topic: Topic? {
    didSet {
        println(topic!.words)
        for word in topic!.words {
            println(word.description)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in RealmSwift (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1876) that should be fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/1882.